# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: jquery, undefined, typeerror

I have some jQuery code like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.menuLink").click(function () {
        elementClick = $(this).attr("href");
        destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
        if ($.browser.safari) {
            $('.info').animate({
                scrollTop: destination
            }, 1100);
        } else {
            $('.info').animate({
                scrollTop: destination
            }, 1100);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

When I click the link (class="menuLink") i'm getting error like Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Can someone tell me whats wrong?

Comment: what does `elementClick`  contain?

Comment: Please add HTML markup of `menuLink`

Comment: Yep what hungerpain and manoj.admlab said, the problem is probably in the href it self, and it is plain wrong or it doesn't have an "#" before it and you try to target it. (but we we need the html to verify xd)

Comment: <a id="home" onclick="javascript:ajaxpage('main/', 'content-wrapper');return loadPage()" class="menuLink" href="#main">

Comment: this link is loads content via ajax on <div> element

Comment: you also have an `onclick` attribute over there. That might take redence over ur click event @user2580942

Comment: understand the reason.
and whether there is an alternative method?
href="#main" must